# Using a Macro to take a screenshot of a website and then pasting it

Tags: vba, ms-word, webpage-screenshot

I am trying to take a screenshot of the webpage linked below and then paste it into word. I have a bit of code that should do that but every time it runs it get a `hwnd = 0` error window. Can someone point me as to where I'm going wrong please.

Web Page: https://www.makro.co.za/groceries-and-toiletries/protex-/br-soap-deep-clean-/br-1-x-150g--338971001EA

```
Sleep 5000

'~~> Get the caption of IE
IECaption = "Protex Soap Deep Clean (1 x 150g)- Lowest Prices & Specials Online | Makro - Internet Explorer"

'~~> Get handle of IE
hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, IECaption)

If hwnd = 0 Then
    MsgBox "IE Window Not found!"
    Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`ShellWindows` are Internet Explorer AND File Explorer windows.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows
For Each window in AllWindows
    msgbox window.locationname & vbcrlf & typename(window.parent) & vbcrlf & window.name
Next
```

Or the `window` object above being an IE object.

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate2 "www.google.com.au"
ie.visible=true
wscript.sleep 5000
ie.refresh2
```

Comment: Ok it seems to be coming from the ie caption as I just ran it for the homepage and it worked!!! I know it is a very amateur ask... but how does one get the accurate page caption?